# How to deal with duplicate bounty questions?

Tags: discussion, bounty, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507930/how-prove-this-inequality-sum-i-j-1nx-ix-j-ge-n-sum-i-1nx) is a duplicate of [a previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73945/stuck-trying-to-prove-an-inequality) (although the motivations are apparently different). At the time of writing, the answers in the newer thread are, in my humble opinion, much nicer than those (including mine -_-: ) given in the old one. Bounties have been offered to both questions and the bounty to the new question is still active.

Personally, I do not want the newer question closed, but since this is a duplicate, I am curious to know if there is any policy or consensus about how to handle this situation. Is it appropriate to close one of the two bounty questions? Why or why not?

Comment: Bounty, not bonus.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. Amended.

Comment: If the answers in the newer thread are much nicer, just close the old question as a duplicate of the new one. /2c.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thanks, that makes sense. The old thread is now closed.

Answer (score 7):

On the technical side, note that: ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties))

> Normal users cannot vote to close questions with active bounties on them.

(Past bounties are not a problem.) This is because closing a question prevents new answers to be added, and in the event the closing is justified we (the moderators) will have to manually go in to refund the active bounty.

---

On a separate note, the fact that the question remained open for long enough for a bounty to be placed probably meant that it was not that noticeable as a duplicate (though we do have a lot of questions!). For the time being, while the bounty is open, I think it suffices to indicate, as you did in the comments (perhaps better on both questions), that the two questions are duplicates.

If you (or anyone else) feel strongly about closing one as the duplicate of the other, you (or anyone else) can just wait until the respective lock (due to the active bounty) expires and vote to close as usual.